# How to add values beside elements in an array in bubble sort algorithm in java

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, int, bubble-sort

Hi I have the following bubble sort algorithm (generic code taken from another site) and I would like to have numbers next to each element of the array as it gets sorted. For example when I run it and it sorts out the array, next to each element it should have the number 1 as this is the first of many sorting algorithms I am using. So to demonstrate:
My results after sorting will look like:

```
4 1
27 1
54 1
321 1
542 1
654 1
887 1
1023 1
```

As you can see, the number 1 is inserted into the each element of the array as it is being sorted in the algorithm. Can someone help me with this?

Sorting algorithm:

```java
public static <E extends Comparable<? super E>> void bubbleSort(E[] comparable) {
    boolean changed = false;
    do {
        changed = false;
        for (int a = 0; a < comparable.length - 1; a++) {
            if (comparable[a].compareTo(comparable[a + 1]) > 0) {
                E tmp = comparable[a];
                comparable[a] = comparable[a + 1];
                comparable[a + 1] = tmp;
                changed = true;
            }
        }
    } while (changed);
}
```

Comment: you just want the number "1" printed out with each element?

Comment: yes, it may sound a bit silly but thats all I need. But I need it to add to each element as it gets sorted, not before

Comment: The animation given here : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort is great to understand whats going on inside bubble sort

Comment: hmmm I see. It takes many iterations for just one element to finally cement its place. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you have sorted do the following to print:

```
for (int i = 0 ; i < comparable.length ; i++){
    System.out.println(comparable[i] + " 1" );
 }
```

Comment: Is there anyway to actually add it while its sorting?

Comment: I didn't really get as to what 'while sorting' means? Bubble sort would traverse through the array a number of times generally before all numbers are bubbled to the right place. When would you want it to happen? When numbers are in their final place? And I suspect your representation would want a conversion to String

Comment: basically, when each comparison gets made and an element finally finds its place then I want that element to have the number 1 next to it, i.e just as it gets sorted.

Comment: Actually, this solution should work for you.. you say you want to print the number 1 after the number is in it's final sorted place, right? When you print all elements in the array after they've been sorted, isn't that doing effectively what you're saying?

Comment: i dnt want to just simply add 1 at the end when they have all been sorted, I want to add 1 to each element one by one as its sorted (put in its correct position).